# Elevation shadow not visible for Toolbar with Basic Activity

Tags: android, android-elevation

I created a "Basic Activity" with Android Studio and attempted to create an elevation shadow on an API 28 Pixel device, using the answer from [toolbar-not-showing-elevation-in-android-9-api-28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818304/toolbar-not-showing-elevation-in-android-9-api-28?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, there is no elevation shadow displayed. The `activity_main.xml` file currently is:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Why does the elevation shadow no longer work on `Toolbar`?

Comment: Can you post a simple project with that setup at github?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the XML that you provided, add `android:clipChildren="false"` to the *CoordinatorLayout*. This will permit the shadow to be drawn outside the bounds of the *AppBarLayout*.

The XML now looks like this (simplified here):

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            app:title="The Toolbar"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

This is really going to be enough for the shadow to be displayed. The problem that I had here was that the shadow was *so* faint on API 28 and 29 that I could not distinguish it from the toolbar.

To make the shadow more visible, create a styles file for v28 and add the following to the application's theme:

```
<item name="android:spotShadowAlpha">0.5</item>
```

It seems that the default alpha value is too faint to be readily seen. This value corrects the problem.

["Playing with elevation in Android (part 1)"](https://tips.seebrock3r.me/playing-with-elevation-in-android-part-1-36b901287249) does a good job of explaining this issue.

The layout now looks like this on an API 29 emulator:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `elevation` for `AppBarLayout` to achieve the shadow.
**Example** (in example, I set marginEnd and color white for `Toolbar` just for see the shadow easily)

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I tested on Pixel emulator (android 9), Huawei device (android 8) and it work (shadow display).

I think if the parent `ViewGroup` have width height equal to children, it will not show the shadow of children. I try your case with different `ViewGroup`, like `ContrainstLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and get same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
        app:titleView="@layout/toolbar_sub_category_title"
        tools:ignore="Overdraw" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```